# CSS problem - horizontal scrollbar hides the content

Tags: css, overflow

I have a problem with this one... because it gives me the scrollbar but the height remains the same so the text is covered by the scroll bar...

```
<td class='messages'><div style='border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;background-color:#66C2FF;height:' class='messages'>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</div>
</td>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks fine to me in Firefox 6, Chrome 13, Safari 5.1, Opera 11.5 and IE9. Which version are you testing in? Sounds like an IE7 problem to me.

Comment: It's busted for me in IE8 =)  (I know...why do I have IE 8???).  I think the problem is the missing `height` value (as @andreas mentions in his answer).  He needs `Height:50px` or something (big enough to show the text with the scroll bar)

Comment: Why do you need to specify the height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your css to an external style sheet and use a conditional comment to target just the browsers you are having a problem with (I have used lower than or equal to IE7 as I cannot replicate in IE8). I have added padding to the bottom.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/Vx9HZ/

Put the conditional comment in the `<head>` like this:

```
<head>
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <style>div.messages {padding:0 0 22px;}</style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**CSS:** Moved to external style sheet.

```
div.messages {
    border:0px;
    padding:0 0 0;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color:#66C2FF;
}
```

**HTML:** Stripped out styling.

```
<td class='messages'>
    <div class='messages'>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: @user924770: Could you post more code then so I can see the affect you are talking about. Also are the scrollbars *meant* to appear or are you trying to make the `div` expand to fit the content?

Comment: <table style='width:80%;'>
<tr>
<td>

<table style='width:100%;'>
<tr>
<td class='messages'> 
<div class='messages' style='width:100%;overflow-x:auto'>
<?php echo $messages; ?>
</div> 
</td> 
</tr>
</table>

</td> 
</tr>
</table>

Comment: @user924770: I am happy I could help. But I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by `"the td is in a table so it makes it different"`. The code above doesn't help me as I cant see a test case and so I can't tell what you are seeing.

Comment: ok well you can add this html code to the jfiddle script you made: <table width='80%'><tr><td width='20%'>here is a lot of words and it makes this content not misbehave</td><td width='80%'><table width='100%'><tr><td>A IMAGE WILL GO HERE WITH WIDTH OF 60PX</td><td class='messages'><div class='messages'>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div></td><tr></table></td></tr></table> and that is kind of what is happening in my real file...

Comment: my table gets too wide and if i make the table-layout fixed then the div is hanging out of the table

Comment: don't bother i found a type-o in my html! you got the solution!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then the following should solve your issue and ALWAYS break a line to accommodate the width if specified. Put this in your style="".

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

PS. Also, you have "height:" with no height specified.

Comment: yeah srry i already fixed that but it still won't work and word-wrap isn't all that cross-browser....

Comment: I'm pretty sure that some browsers simply don't break "long words" and there is no way around it. But that is what word-wrap is for and most browsers indeed to support it. Otherwise, try nowrap="nowrap" on the TD, it might force it on legacy browsers.

Comment: This will not solve the problem. Even if the words did wrap, the scrollbar will still cover the bottom of the text.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <td class='messages'>
      <div style='border:0px;padding:0px;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;background-color:#66C2FF; height= 50PX; class=messages;'>
      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      </div>
   </td>
  </body>
</html>
```

I specified a `height` for the `div` that was big enough to show the text and the scroll bar.  =)  Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a good solution except for that the length of the text and content can vary on my page.... so 50 px wont always work