# Container expands width with its content. Make vertical scrollbar outside, not inside

Tags: html, css

Here is the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzqNvZ)

I want to have the container expands width with its content. At the same time, its height is fixed. If overflowed vertically, there should be a vertical scrollbar.

Now, `overflow:auto` makes the scrollbar somehow inside the container, covering the content. That's not what I want.

If I use `overflow:scroll`, the scrollbar will be outside, but it's always there even when there is no overflow.

How can I solve the dilemma here? Tested on Windows, latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS problem - horizontal scrollbar hides the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294956/css-problem-horizontal-scrollbar-hides-the-content)

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` to `.container1` class. Have 2 div containers

[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/oLXLvr)

Comment: I have updated the Pen for you this removes the horizontal scrollbar also http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/oLXLBN

Comment: I think your answer can be just simplified to adding `padding-right:20px` and set `overflow:auto`. No need for two containers. However, when vertical scrollbar isn't present, there is still `20px` right padding. That's what I want to get rid of when no scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems not so difficult.
Have you tried setting *width* to *auto*?

Try using following **CSS**; It will output the same result as you require.

```
.container {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Setting width to auto will make the div to expand according to its content and there will not be horizontal scroll bar as you want.
Then setting just overflow-y to scroll will give you only vertical scroll bar.

Hope That Helps...

Comment: you can accept this as your answer if it resolves your problem. :)

Comment: It'll make the scrollbar always there even when there is no overflow. I've already mentioned it in the original question. Thanks anyway.